# Add the product image to Woocommerce my account order view

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I would like to add image on my account view order pages in Woocommerce.some one I am able to get the image but the size is too large  and I don't know where I need to add this code:

```
<?php 
    // Get a list of all items that belong to the order
    $products = $order->get_items();

    // Loop through the items and get the product image
    foreach( $products as $product ) {                  

        $product_obj = new WC_Product( $product["product_id"] );

        echo $product_obj->get_image();

    }
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Here is the location on the View order pages, wher I would like to add the product image:

[image: view order]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following hooked function will do the job *(You may need to add some CSS style rules)*:

```
// Display the product thumbnail in order view pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'display_product_image_in_order_item', 20, 3 );
function display_product_image_in_order_item( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ) {
    // Targeting view order pages only
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) ) {
        $product   = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
        $thumbnail = $product->get_image(array( 36, 36)); // Get the product thumbnail (from product object)
        if( $product->get_image_id() > 0 )
            $item_name = '<div class="item-thumbnail">' . $thumbnail . '</div>' . $item_name;
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

**Note** the [`WC_Product` method `get_image()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1793-1812) uses Wordpress `get_the_post_thumbnail()` internally.

---

> **Update:** added `if( $product->get_image_id() > 0 )` to the code, to display the product image, only when it exist.

Comment: Hi @Loic TheAztec it help me but if product image is not available in some products so what can i write else condition because when i click on order history the page reloads and nothing it seems  its whole blank your help will be appriciated

Comment: @ParthShah Sorry I just tested that now, it works without any problem like you describe. My updated code, display the item image only if it exist. If there is no image set for the product, it keep the normal behavior of woocommerce. So there is something else that you have done, another customization, something in your theme or a plugin that is making trouble.

Comment: Can u help me as i have uploaded that order from csv so that  product are not in product category  so i think it wont get any product id  as in database  product id is null so what could be condition for null ...

Comment: @ParthShah Sorry, but you should better ask a new question, as I really don't catch your issue.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I added your code in function.php and I am getting the image in the purchase list instead of the order list.

Comment: @user9437856 **It is not for order list,** read the question… Yes it still works in WooCommerce 4.9.2 on My Account > orders > **single view order**… If it doesn't is because something else it's making trouble, so it can be your theme, a plugin or some lther code added by you.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, Yes, I deleted my first comment. I just added the code in the function and checked my order page. It was not displaying so I thought some issue with the code.  Then I click on the view button and there I got an image.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, I ask the new question for displaying the image on the order page  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66151448/what-hook-i-have-to-use-to-display-the-product-image-on-order-page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the main image, you just need to fetch the thumbnail via get_the_post_thumbnail():

```html
<?php 
    // Get a list of all items that belong to the order
    $products = $order->get_items();

    // Loop through the items and get the product image
    foreach( $products as $product ) {                  

        $product_obj = new WC_Product( $product["product_id"] );

        echo get_the_post_thumbnail();

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write it on woocommerce/template/order/ordr-details-item.php

```
echo '<div class="product-imgae">'.$product->get_image(array( 80, 80)).'</div>';
```

this will give you a 80x80 size image change it according to your neesd.