# Add the sku to order items on my account order view pages in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, sku

In Woocommerce, I am customizing my view order in MyAccount. I already added the Product images with this answer code: [Add the product image to Woocommerce my account order view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50936156/add-the-product-image-to-woocommerce-my-account-order-view/50937087#50937087)

Now I would like to add the Product SKU to The View order pages but, I don't know how to get it.

Anyone have an Idea?

Comment: If you don't make changes to a stackOverFlow answer code, please just add the link to your question. Anyways when using an existing answer thread you should please always add the link in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing your code with the following to display the product SKU in order items:

```
// Display the product thumbnail in order view pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'display_product_image_in_order_item', 20, 3 );
function display_product_image_in_order_item( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ) {
    // Targeting view order pages only
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) ) {
        $product   = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
        $thumbnail = $product->get_image(array( 36, 36)); // Get the product thumbnail (from product object)
        // The thumbnail
        if( $product->get_image_id() > 0 )
            $item_name = '<div class="item-thumbnail">' . $thumbnail . '</div>' . $item_name;
        // The SKU
        if( $sku = $product->get_sku() )
            $item_name .= '<br><div class="product-sku">' . $sku . '</div>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). It should works.