# Display product image on Woocommerce My Account Downloads section

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I’ve got a problem that I can’t seem to figure out. I’m trying to add the product image to each item in the my-account/downloads/ section. I have tried multiple codes that I found but none seem to work for me.

I am using 3 plugins with all other plugins disabled trying to figure this out. These 3 plugins are required, so I need this to work with all 3 of these plugins activated.

The 3 plugins are:

**Woocommerce Memberships**

**Woocommerce Subscriptions**

**Woocommerce Subscriptions Downloads**

All my products are virtual so I need an image next to their name in the downloads section. I'm pulling my hair out here... Anyway, to the things I've tried.

I have tried this code which I found in [This form post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/product-image-in-download-section/)

```
function my_account_downloads_column_download_product( $download ) {
    // Get $product object from product ID
    $product = wc_get_product( $download['product_id'] );
    
    // Get thumbnail
    $thumbnail = $product->get_image(array( 36, 36)); // Get the product thumbnail (from product object)
    
    // Image found
    if( $product->get_image_id() > 0 ) {
        $item_name = '<div class="item-thumbnail">' . $thumbnail . '</div>';
        echo $item_name;
    }

    echo '<a href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $product->get_name() . '</a>';
 }
```

I also tried the other codes present in that form but they didn’t work for me.

Based on *[Add the product image to Woocommerce my account order view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50936156/add-the-product-image-to-woocommerce-my-account-order-view/50937087#50937087)* answer code, which works great for the view-order page, I have made some changes trying to make it work for my-account/downloads/ section.

Here’s my code attempt:

```
// Display the product thumbnail in order view pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_downloads_title', 'display_product_image_in_downloads', 20, 3 
    );
function display_product_image_in_downloads( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ) {
    // Targeting view order pages only
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'downloads' ) ) {
        $product       = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
        $product_image = $product->get_image(array( 80, 80)); // Get the product thumbnail (from product 
    object)
        $item_name     = '<div class="item-thumbnail">' . $product_image . '</div>' . $item_name;
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

I changed `woocommerce_my_account_my_downloads_title`  out to every one I could find related to downloads on the [Woocommerce Hook Reference page](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)

However, none of them seem to work for me.

I tried to modify the template files by copying them to my childtheme / woocommerce / order / order-downloads.php, also childtheme / woocommerce / myaccount / downloads.php, and childtheme / woocommerce / myaccount / my-downloads.php. I couldn’t get any of that to work so I removed it from my childtheme and tried the codes above in my childthemes functions.php file.

I have scoured the internet trying to find a solution but, every one of them don’t seem to work for me. I have a feeling that **Woocommerce Subscriptions Downloads** could be the problem, but it's a must plugin for me. I probably just didn’t do something right or missed something but I can’t seem to find out what.

Can someone help me figure this out? That would be awesome.

All I want is the product image next to the downloadable product. I only sell downloadable products and there are hundreds of products. An image would just help the customer find what they want to download so much easier.

Answer (score 2):

On My Account Downloads section the related template is `myaccount/downloads.php`.
This template call `order/order-downloads.php` to display the downloads table.

So the right hook to be used is `woocommerce_account_downloads_column_{$column_id}` composite action hook, where**`$column_id`** is `download-product` to target the product name.

> Now for Woocommerce Subscriptions Downloads, I don't know if the following will work.

So the right code is going to be:

```
// Display the product thumbnail in order view pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_column_download-product', 'display_product_image_on_account_downloads' );
function display_product_image_on_account_downloads( $download ) {
    // Targeting view order pages only
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'downloads' ) ) return;

    if ( $download['product_id'] > 0 ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $download['product_id'] ); // The product object
        $image   = $product->get_image( array(50, 50) ); // The product image

        if ( $download['product_url'] ) {
            echo $image . '<a href="' . esc_url( $download['product_url'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $download['product_name'] ) . '</a>';
        } else {
            echo $image . esc_html( $download['product_name'] );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

@LoicTheAztec 's answer works but I changed it a little bit, because:
`order-downloads.php` content is also called on the `order-received` endpoint when a Digital product is ordered.
So when using `if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'downloads' ) ) return;` - it will show the image on the `/my-account/downloads` page but the Product title field on the `/checkout/order-received` will become empty. No product title, and no image.

So, I solved it by changing: 
`if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'downloads' ) ) return;`
to
`if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( array ('downloads' , 'order-received') )) return;`