# Change column titles from downloads table on Woocommerce emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, download, email-notifications

I'm trying to change the "product" column title for downloadable products on customers email notification after completing a purchase.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `woocommerce_email_downloads_columns` filter hook will allow you to change the column label name to something else:

```
// Change email downloads specific column label name
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_downloads_columns', 'filter_wc_email_downloads_columns' );
function filter_wc_email_downloads_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['download-product'] = __( 'Name', 'woocommerce' );

    return $columns;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Similar: [Change column titles from downloads table on Woocommerce Thankyou page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024825/change-column-titles-from-downloads-table-on-woocommerce-thankyou-page/63025725#63025725)