# Display product thumbnails on WooCommerce My account orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails, orders

I am trying to display product thumbnails on WooCommerce My account > Orders list, beside the order number.

Below is the screenshot of the order
[image]

What hook I have to use to display the image?

I tried [Add the product image to Woocommerce my account order view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50936156/add-the-product-image-to-woocommerce-my-account-order-view/50937087#50937087) answer code, but it displays the image on single view orders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated**

You can use the following to add product thumbnails on WooCommerce My account > Orders list, beside the order number:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order-number', 'my_account_orders_product_thumbnails', 20, 1 );
function my_account_orders_product_thumbnails( $order ) {
    echo '<a href="'. wc_get_endpoint_url('view-order') . $order->get_id()  . '/' . '">' . '#' . $order->get_order_number() . '</a>';

    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $product   = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
        $thumbnail = $product->get_image(array( 36, 36)); // Get the product thumbnail (from product object)
        if( $product->get_image_id() > 0 ) {
            echo '&nbsp;' . $thumbnail;
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can add a new column with the product thumbnails after the order number like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'filter_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 10, 1 );
function filter_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns( $columns ) {
    $new_column = array( 'order-number' => $columns['order-number']);
    unset($columns['order-number']);

    $new_column['order-thumbnails'] = '';

    return array_merge($new_column, $columns);
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order-thumbnails', 'filter_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order', 10, 1 );
function filter_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order( $order ) {
    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $product   = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
        $thumbnail = $product->get_image(array( 36, 36)); // Get the product thumbnail (from product object)
        if( $product->get_image_id() > 0 ) {
            echo $thumbnail . '&nbsp;' ;
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Yes it's displaying the image but the order number action link is missing. I need to use the anchor link here     echo '#' . $order->get_order_number();

Comment: I am learning woocommerce, I just need to know in case If I have to show the image then order number then where I have to change the code?

Comment: Yes, I will accept your answer and you deserve the upvote. In your first answer, the anchor link is not working. It's redirect on 404

Comment: Yes, In the first answer you added order-view but it should be view-order.

Comment: Yes, I updated my code. Thanks for the help

Comment: Would you help me out with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181812/what-is-the-hook-to-change-the-size-from-thumbnail-to-the-actual-image-size-for

Comment: @user9437856 I Have answered your question (no need of hooks)…

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me. Unfortunately, the function is not working on Woocommerce Pre-Order plugin and in mobile the graphics are so small.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order-number', 'my_account_orders_product_thumbnails', 20, 1 );
function my_account_orders_product_thumbnails( $order ) {
    echo '<a href="'. wc_get_endpoint_url('view-order') . $order->get_id()  . '/' . '">' . '#' . $order->get_order_number() . '</a>'; 
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $product   = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
        $thumbnail = $product->get_image(array( 36, 36)); // Get the product thumbnail (from product object)
        if( $product->get_image_id() > 0 ) {
            echo '&nbsp;' . $thumbnail;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29857200)